Publicar unicamente una pagina asp net
Actualmente he creado multiples projectos de una sola pagina en un servidor, ya que la base son programas de asp classic.
Es posible que en lugar de tener multiples projectos tener uno solo y ahi tener todas las vistas que yo deseee, pero al momento de agregar una vista nueva o realizar un cambio en algun controlador en especifico, al momento de publicar mi proyecto se puede publicar unicamente donde se aplico el cambio? en lugar de que suban todas las vistas?
